# Find logo for desktop applications using c#

Tags: c#

Good day Users.
I am working on application which maintains list of other applications (like Excel, Word, Adobe Reader, etc.). For each app, i would like to have it's logo to use in `Listview` while displaying whole list. For sure, it will not be possible for all apps (especially for unpopular ones.) but for well known ones. 
 
Logos can be found in google and then manually inserted one by one, but the problem is that, number of apps in the list is more than ten thousand. 
Using Google Image Search API is not good solution, since it only allows 100 request in a day.
If anyone know how to do this, or has any suggestion, please let me know ^^ 
thanks

Comment: Read this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/25086/where-are-my-icons-in-windows-7). This talks about fetching icons in Win7.

Comment: Are you sure you want to present a list of 10,000+ to users???? Not really good, you should at least break then down into application type and put some kind of filter. Additionally, you really want to keep the images on your servers otherwise your reliant on third party servers being available.

Comment: @bilpor Sure bilpor, it will be saved locally in Db and won't be downloaded every time user opens <code>Listview</code>.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the path to the exe, you can get it's icon using the static method of Icon class [ExtractAssociatedIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but app may not be installed on a machine. i would like solution which uses some web resource, like when you want to find <code>favicon</code> of a web page and send [link] http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=*. request.

Comment: If the app is not installed on the machine, I'm guessing you have some kind of catalog service which provides the full list of apps. I would put the responsibility of providing the icon image into that catalog service, and not try to guess one with an external service.

Comment: Right Fede. In my case, list of apps are statically placed in Db and is rarely updated, So my service will be depend on external only at first, while populating icons in Db, if that makes sense.